# How to maintain scroll position of a div when the page loads

Tags: asp.net, scroll, asprepeater

is there a way to scroll-down to a particular div when the page loads? i have 100+ rows so when the page loads i am highlighting the div background based on certain conditions so same way is that possible to position to the particular div?

i am using a repeater with

```
<asp:Repeater EnableViewState="true" ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_ItemDataBound">       
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div style='padding: 10px;' id="mydiv"  runat="server">
                <div>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'> </asp:Label>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:Repeater> 

protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (......)
         mydiv.Attributes.Add("class", "selected_div");
}
```

Comment: checkout this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094589/maintain-scroll-position-of-a-div-within-a-page-on-postback

Answer (score 0):

Use tabindex property of div. set the focus of div using tab-index.

check this link : [Set keyboard focus to a <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754275/set-focus-to-a-div-classic-asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you could use the [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin, on the page's ready function, using your "selected_div" class as selector.
Such as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).scrollTo('.selected_div');
}
```

Without jquery you can use the standard javascript function `.scrollIntoView(true)` on the div element. However, you'd have to locate the element first, in order to call that function.

A combination of both is also valid. Using jquery to locate the selected div using your class selector, and on the element calling `.scrollIntoView(true)`.